# Unique refs for a list of elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to apply refs to a list of elements which are generated by an array, so I can (conditionally) change the class when I feel fit.

```
renderMessageGroup(message) {
    const date = message[0];

    return (
        <li ref={this.messageGroups[date]} key={date}>
            {Object.values(message[1]).map(obj => this.renderMessage(obj, date))}
        </li>
    );
}

renderMessage(obj, date) {
    if(typeof obj != "object") return null;

    if(obj.user == this.context.user.id) this.messageGroups[date].classList.add("self");

    return (
        <div className="message" key={obj._id}>
            {obj.message}
        </div>
    );
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {Object.entries(this.state.messages).map(this.renderMessageGroup)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `ref={this.messageGroups[date]}` is what you're trying to achieve and not what you've already implemented. Have you considered something like [this](https://medium.com/@jalexmayer/react-refs-with-dynamic-names-d2262ab0a0b0)?

For you it could be something like:

```
Object.entries(this.state.messages).forEach(message => {
    this[`messageGroups${message[0]}`] = React.createRef();
})
```

Which you would place in the constructor like a static ref.

Edit: added backticks to the ref string.

Comment: I have a few issues with this; I can't seem to use this inside my constructor because `message` is always undefined. However, if I move it into `componentDidMount` then  `current` is always null. Can't seem to figure it out.